# Problema con Css FlexBox el contenido no abarca el 100%

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

Buenas Tardes espero que puedan ayudarme. Estoy haciendo un layout simple con Flexbox pero no logro que el "contenido" abarque un 100% del espacio disponible, la estructura es sencilla:

- Menú
- Contenido
- Pie

Es importante resaltar que el "Menu" y "Pie" deben tener un **height: auto**, esto para cuando la pantalla cambie de tamaño los items (hijos) puedan adaptarse y ser responsive. Ya estos 2 funcionan como yo los deseo, incluso el "Contenido"  se **expande** a medida que crece, esto esta perfecto!, pero cuando trato que éste **abarque** el 100% del espacio entre el "Menu" y el "Pie" es ahí donde vienen los problemas.

OJO: en el "contenido" deje un Lorem de 600 palabras para que puedan realizar la  prueba de expandirse y así como esta "Lorem600" pueden hacer la prueba de abarcar el 100% del espacio disponible entre el Menú y pie.

Mucho agradecería la ayuda que puedan prestarme (Ya tengo 2 días buscando informacion y no doy con la solución). Gracias!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            outline: 0;
        }
        html,
        body {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            font-family: Verdana, arial, sans-serif;
        }
         #contenedor {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content:flex-start;
        }
        #cabecera {

            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #399;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            align-self: flex-start;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        #contenido {
            margin: 10px 0px;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: yellow;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        #pie {
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #399;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            align-self: flex-end;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .x {
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="cabecera">
            <div class="x">Cabecera</div>
            <div class="x">items</div>
            <div class="x">items2</div>
        </div>

        <div id="contenido">
            <p>Lorem600</p>
        </div>

        <div id="pie">
            <div class="x">items3</div>
            <div class="x">items4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de resolverlo es usando:

- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis): propiedad que especifica la base flexible, la cual es el tamaño inicial de un elemento flexible.

Demo:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
#contenedor {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#contenedor > * {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
#cabecera,
#pie {
  background-color: #399;
  color: #fff;
}
#contenido {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.x {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="cabecera">
    <div class="x">Cabecera</div>
    <div class="x">items</div>
    <div class="x">items2</div>
  </div>

  <div id="contenido">
    <p>Lorem600</p>
  </div>

  <div id="pie">
    <div class="x">items3</div>
    <div class="x">items4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @marcos-gallardo, muchas gracias por responder, el código esta perfecto. Por cultura general por que usas **flex: 100%** y no **flex: 1**; que diferencia existe?

Comment: @MiguelArias, ha sido un error. He actualizado mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Usar un layour horizontal cuando vas a ordenar los elementos de forma vertical no tiene sentido. Deberías usar `flex-direction: column` para que los hijos se ordenen uno luego de otro en forma vertical. Luego, solo necesitas `flex: 1` en el contenido para abarcar el espacio entre el menú y el pie de página.

> Es importante resaltar que el "Menu" y "Pie" **deben tener** un height: auto, esto para cuando la pantalla cambie de tamaño los items (hijos) puedan adaptarse y ser responsive

Falso. No deben tener un alto automático, pueden tener bien un alto fijo y seguiría siendo responsivo, ya que ésto **no depende** de tus estilos iniciales, sino de tu marcado.

Para lograr un diseño como el que deseas el truco está en saber usar la propiedad `flex`. Esta propiedad acepta tres valores:

- Factor de crecimiento
- Factor de encogimiento
- Flex basis

Por defecto el valor de flex es: `0 1 auto`. Esta propiedad afecta al elemento de acuerdo a la orientación del elemento padre. Por ejemplo, si el padre tiene una orientación vertical (`column`) entonces `flex-basis` representará al alto del elemento.

**Ejemplo sticky header y footer**

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: turquoise;
  flex: 0 0 60px;
}

article {
  background-color: gold;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

footer {
  background-color: coral;
  flex: 0 0 60px;
}

.big {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <article>
    <div class="big"></div>
  </article>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @Guz, muchas gracias por responder, el único problema que tuve al probar tu código fue con height: auto, tuve que modificarlo de flex: 0 0 60px a flex: 0 0 **auto** para lograr que los **Items** se apiñaran uno bajo el otro, del resto del codigo esta perfecto.

Comment: Si el menú es vertical, entonces es correcto ponerle un `height: auto` al header. Sin embargo, considera ponerlos horizontal, es más intuitivo. Los menús verticales son por lo general para menús móviles o menús laterales.

Answer (score 1):

Debes cambiar el **flex-direction** por **column** y establecer el valor flex al contenido para que se ajuste al tamaño que quieres.

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
#contenedor {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;    /* El flex-direction debe ser column */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#cabecera {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #399;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#contenido {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;     /* Se le asigna un valor al elemento para que abarque la proporción que necesitas */
}
#pie {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #399;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.x {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="cabecera">
    <div class="x">Cabecera</div>
    <div class="x">items</div>
    <div class="x">items2</div>
  </div>

  <div id="contenido">
    <p>Lorem600</p>
  </div>

  <div id="pie">
    <div class="x">items3</div>
    <div class="x">items4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @Jemonge. muchas gracias por responder, probe tu sugerencia pero te paso igual que a mi, cuando inserto informacion p.e. un Lorem600 y disminuyo la resolución de la pagina, el "Contenido" no se expande empujando el Footer hacia abajo sino éste queda como fijo y por ende se desborda el "Contenido" por detrás del "Footer".